# Change URL Date Parameters by taking them as inputs from user by using HTML Thymeleaf in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I've created a Spring Boot app that consumes external API and returns some results back to the users. The main URL being consumed is

```
https://data.gov.gr/api/v1/query/mdg_emvolio
```

But I can use parameters on it to display results based on specific dates. For example,

```
https://data.gov.gr/api/v1/query/mdg_emvolio?date_from=2022-07-31&date_to=2022-07-31
```

For the above URLs to work I need also to pass a token, which I implement in my Config Class.

My main goal is to give the opportunity to the users to provide the date parameters by selecting them through a form in Thymeleaf, but I can't find a way to do so.

I am showing you a [website example](https://www.data.gov.gr/datasets/mdg_emvolio/) of what I am trying to do (On top you can change the language to english). You can see that you can select from and to dates, as parameters. I want to create something similar in Thymeleaf form and pass it to the URL in my Config Class.

Is it possible in Spring Boot to change in the URL in the Config Class based on user input?

**Config Class**

```
package com.andrekreou.covid.gov.configuration;

import com.andrekreou.covid.gov.model.Covid;
import com.andrekreou.covid.gov.repository.CovidRepo;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference;
import org.springframework.http.*;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

//The configuration class to fetch data from url and execute the insertion
//of the data into the PostgreSQL database
@Configuration
public class CovidConfig {

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(CovidRepo covidRepo){
        return args -> {
            String url = "https://data.gov.gr/api/v1/query/mdg_emvolio";
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            headers.set("Authorization","Token 8329eb4fa30e567d9e3f6bfed266c8cb4c9c94ad");

            HttpEntity<Object> request = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

            ResponseEntity<List<Covid>> postEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
                    url,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    request,
                    new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {
                    });

            List<Covid> covidList = postEntity.getBody();
            covidRepo.saveAll(covidList);
            System.out.println(covidList);
        };
    }
}
```

**Controller Class**

```
package com.andrekreou.covid.gov.controller;

import com.andrekreou.covid.gov.service.Service;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@Controller
public class WelcomePageController {

    private final Service service;

    @Autowired
    public WelcomePageController(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    // welcome.message gets injected via application.properties
    @Value("${welcome.message}")
    private String message;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String main(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("message", message);
        return "welcomepage";
    }

    //Method to handle the HTTP request for showing DB contents
    @GetMapping("/show-contents")
    public String showAllRates(HttpServletRequest request){
        request.setAttribute("covidcases", service.showAllCases());
        return "databasecontents";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/input")
    public String index(
            @RequestParam(value = "date_from", required = false) String date_from,
            @RequestParam(value = "date_to", required = false) String date_to
    ) {
        return "input";
    }
}
```

**Thymeleaf View**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Spring Boot Thymeleaf Hello World Example</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/styles/db.css}"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>


</head>

<body>

<ul>
    <li><a href="https://localhost:8443/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://github.com/Andreas-Kreouzos" target="_blank">Github</a></li>
</ul>

<main role="main" class="container">

    <div class="starter-template">
        <h1>Cryptocurrency News</h1>
    </div>

</main>
    <!--Display DB contents on HTML and Thymeleaf-->

    <div class="container text-center" id="tasksDiv">
        <hr>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Area</th>
                    <th>Area ID</th>
                    <th>Reference Date</th>
                    <th>Total Dose 1</th>
                    <th>Total Dose 2</th>
                    <th>Total Dose 3</th>
                    <th>Total Vaccinations</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr th:each="covid: ${covidcases}">
                        <td th:text="${covid.id}"> </td>
                        <td th:text="${covid.area}"> </td>
                        <td th:text="${covid.areaid}"> </td>
                        <td th:text="${covid.referencedate}"> </td>
                        <td th:text="${covid.totaldose1}"> </td>
                        <td th:text="${covid.totaldose2}"> </td>
                        <td th:text="${covid.totaldose3}"> </td>
                        <td th:text="${covid.totalvaccinations}"> </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**User Input**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Spring Boot Thymeleaf Hello World Example</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/styles/main.css}"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>

</head>

<body>

<ul>
    <li><a href="https://localhost:8443/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://github.com/Andreas-Kreouzos" target="_blank">Github</a></li>
</ul>

<form th:action="@{/input}">
    <input type="text" th:name="date_from"/>
    <input type="text" th:name="date_to"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Apologies if I have misunderstood, but are you saying you cannot add a [`<form>` element to your Thymeleaf template](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#creating-a-form)? I don't see a form in the template in the question.

Comment: My bad, forgot to add my form view. I updated my question. The parameters are passing to the controller but I want my url in my config class to accept them as inputs. So instead of `https://data.gov.gr/api/v1/query/mdg_emvolio`, I will getting for example `https://data.gov.gr/api/v1/query/mdg_emvolio?date_from=2022-07-31&date_to=2022-07-31` based from user input.

Comment: Thank you - but I am still confused: Are submitting your form data to a 3rd party web site `th:action="@{https://data.gov.gr/...}"`? Not to your own web app? How does that work?

Comment: It was just for testing purposes, just to see how the url parameterization works. I updated my code once again to "/input".

Comment: Your `index()` method in your controller is using `@RequestParam(value = "participant", required = false) String participant`. But your form has defined `date_from` and `date_to` - not `participant`. So, that is not going to work. Is it just that the code you are showing us is significantly different from the code you are actually using?

Comment: No this is the actual code. I updated once again bsed on your comments. If I put some dates in the form the result is `https://localhost:8443/input?date_from=2022-07-31&date_to=2022-07-31`. I have to find a way not only to correct this but also to pass in my config class.

Comment: OK, thank you. I think, maybe, you might have misunderstood what Thymeleaf can do for you. Thymeleaf only exists on the server. It cannot manipulate data entered by a user into an input field on a web page. You use your controller code to grab those values from `?date_from=2022-07-31&date_to=2022-07-31`. You can do that in various ways - but using `@RequestParam(value = "date_from", required = false) String dateFrom` is one way. Now you have your `dateFrom` string (and similar for your `dateTo` string).

Comment: To be honest, I think you would be better off asking a much more focused question (how to pass these data strings to your config class), and only give us the absolute minimal amount of code needed to show that very specific problem. Having said that, I don't know why it's set up as a config class and a command line runner class. Getting data from a remote API is a service. It's easy enough to invoke a service object with parameters. So, maybe some restructuring? Sorry, that is probably the best I can suggest. I know it's not a "solution".